# Microsoft Word - copying multiple rows of a table that have different layout

Tags: microsoft-word

Apologies as I feel like this *should* be simple, but I've struggled to resolve it our to find the right way to 'search' my question to find a previous answer.

In our office we use a number of Word documents which have tables within them. The individual rows within those tables have different layouts (vertical breaks in different places). We need to be able to duplicate a run of, say, 4 rows with differing layouts to extend the table.

Is there a simple way to go about this?

To attempt to illustrate, let's say I need to duplicate the middle three rows of this table, so that they are repeated one (or more) times, but the unbroken rows at the start and end (which may already contain text) are retained.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the newer versions of Word (2016 and I think 2013) you can copy and paste those cells specifically by using the Paste Option **Insert as New Rows**.

[image]

Completely select your desired three rows and copy to the clipboard.  Then paste on the row above where you want the new rows inserted (so, with the cursor pointed at the last row of the set of three rows you just copied).

Comment: That works in some examples, but in others we end up with cell-widths screwed up forcing the table to expand beyond the page margins.

This *may* be down to the age/formatting of some of our documents I guess, as in some cases it works fine but not all.

Comment: That's probably due to inconsistencies in how the table was constructed in the first place.  Can you select the entire table and update its properties, such as forcing it to a specific "Preferred width"?  That might prevent or correct issues with page overflow.

Comment: Having checked, Preferred Width is in place, so doesn't look like that's the issue. I'm still pretty sure it's *something* to do with the age and (poor) formatting of the tables though

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you may select the whole table, copy it, then paste right after the original table. Word will duplicate the table & join both tables, preserving the formatting & column widths. Then simply delete the extra rows.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about how to do this in Word but a relatively simple workaround would be open an Excel side by side, copy the table to Excel, do table operations within Excel, and then copy the table back to Word.

Comment: I've tried that, unfortunately it throws up some issues with sizing/placement of the 'new' table when you paste it back - but it's a reasonable 'last resort' option.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the simple test that I did:

1. Select the rows that need to be duplicated, and then, on the **Insert** tab, in the **Tables** group, click **Table** > **Quick Tables** > **Save Selection to Quick Tables Gallery**.
2. To add those rows to the end of a table to extend it, place the cursor in the paragraph right after the table, and then click **Table** > **Quick Tables**, and select the Quick Table that you saved. By default, when you add a new table immediately after an existing table, Word merges them into a single table.

   You can also add rows into the middle of an existing table in the same way. Just place the cursor in the row that you want to add rows before.

Comment: Thanks cnread, unfortunately - being as trusted as we are by the company - the 'Save Selection...' option is greyed out. I suspect I may have to accept defeat on this one.